# Django add permission to access URL before view methods are called

Tags: django, python-2.7

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^A/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^B/$', logout_page),
url(r'^C/$', c_method),
url(r'^D/$', D_method),)
```

In the above URL configuration, I would like allow only router **A** to particular set of users, and remaining **B,C and D** to particular set of user. how can I do this using URL configuration.

Please note, my application already has got nearly 80 URL'S, now I cannot edit and add permission to each method. So what I am trying do is, as soon as URL is called, it need pass through the permission, before it actually calls views methods. Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: This isn't clear at all. What "routers" are you talking about?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I mean URL

Comment: you have create custom decorators and use it on top of function and in custom decorator you have to define your condition on which condition you want to raise permissions denied error.

Comment: @AbiWaqas an example would be great

Comment: posting in an answer wait

Answer (score 0):

You can create custum decorator like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
    def your_decorator_name(function):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            your condition
            if your conditioon is true == True:
                 return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                 raise PermissionDenied

        wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
        wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
        return wrap
```

and use it in function like this

```
from ur_file_location import your_decorator_name
    @your_decorator_name
    def permision_demo(request):
        return 'hola'
```